# Purpose of Vue instance in app.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.4

New to Vue, and I have a question. Im using Laravel 5.4 for back-end and Vue.js (2.1.10) for front-end. Laravel creates an app.js file where you are supposed to pull in all your components and libraries, but it also includes a vue instance

app.js

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

My question is why? I understood that on each of my resources/views, I create a new vue instance and if I need to dynamically add components, that view's Vue instance controls it. What is the purpose of the instance in app.js? I am moving towards releasing this site into the wild, and I want to make sure I fully understand what is going on for future expansion.

Update

I am using laravel-mix. And my site is a collection of SPA. For instance, the organization.blade.php view is a SPA that allows you to to view and work with organiztions. And the equipment.blade.php is a SPA that does the same for instruments.

Comment: Generally, you don't create a new instance of Vue on each of your views. Usually you use Vue to create a SPA, a page without a need to reload. You create a single Vue instance (which is the code you posted does) and then just display different Vue components depending on the state.

Comment: Are you using `laravel mix` or`webpack` to build your JS files?